# Changing ion-content's background color

Tags: ionic2, background-color, ionic3

How can I change the background color of an `ion-content` in ionic 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app.scss add :

```
.bg-style {
    background: red;
}
```

and apply style to content as in your component Html file :

```
<ion-content class="bg-style">
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to theme/variebles.css and add

```
$background-ios-color: #0F0029;
$background-md-color: #0F0029;
```

For ios and android backgrounds